# SELECT Not returning as many results as I expect

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select a set of results from a 3 tables. My object is to return all members form the members table with scores from a scores table.

```
$sql = "SELECT member.id, member.firstName, member.lastName, compScore.score1, 
               compScore.score2, compScore.score3, compScore.score4, 
               compScore.score5, compScore.score6, compScore.score7, 
               compScore.score8, compScore.memberId, teamMember.memberId, 
               teamMember.teamId
        FROM member
        JOIN compScore ON member.id = compScore.memberId
        JOIN teamMember ON teamMember.memberId = member.id";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

var_dump($result);
echo $conn->error;

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo $row['firstName'];
          echo $row['score1'];
    }
  }
```

The above query only outputs a single result and not all the members from the member table.

There should be 3 members output but I only get the 1st one.

Here is my result via a var_dump:

```
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { 
    ["current_field"]=> int(0)
    ["field_count"]=> int(14) 
    ["lengths"]=> NULL 
    ["num_rows"]=> int(1) 
    ["type"]=> int(0) 
} jon3
```

**UPDATE**

Tables:

```
member
id, firstName, lastName

team
id, name

teamMember
id, memberId, teamId

compScore
score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7, score8, memberId
```

Comment: Try using a LEFT JOIN on both the joins

Comment: Aha, seems to be a touch closer, it shows me all members but only one score for the first member...

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Would you have any other suggestions on the scores front?

Comment: Not without a bit more detail about the tables and data in the tables

Comment: @RiggsFolly - thanks man, I have just updated the question

Comment: A bit of data woudl be useful too

Comment: @RiggsFolly it did actually work what you advised. Thank you.

Comment: Took a closer look at the data and the penny dropped. :)

Comment: @PhpDude, I would recommend testing the query out on the database directly and make sure the query is correct there and then move it to php, then you can determine if the query results are working on the db or if there is an issue with php.